# cannot run flutter "pub upgrade"

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

everytime i try to run any flutter command it gives me an error of "Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds..".
like the following screenshot:

[image]

also if this anything to do witht this error; the following message appears and neveer leaves "Initializing the Flutter SDK. This may take a few minutes.", like the following message:

[image]

any idea how to fix this ?

i tried to uninstall dart and flutter extension from vscode but it didn't work, i also tried to remove the flutter sdk folder and installing it again but this also didn't work, i searched many webistes and the answer was to delete the cahce folder from the bin folder, and after that running pub cache repair, but it gave me the same error "Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...", so it also didn't work.

[image]

i tried to run flutter doctor and this what it gave me :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Fsw.png)